# how can solve the connection issue during connecting visual studio to mac?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

This is the error while connecting to mac server

[image: The related image of error while connecting to mac server]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.